# external inheritance private member is accessible in initializer?

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio 2015 community edition.

this is the code:

```
class Circle{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Circle(Circle &n);
};

Circle::Circle(Circle &n): radius(n.radius){ //<---this is working, why??
}
```

why is external inheritance private member accessible in initializer?

i get that this is needed when the class don't have getters on them, but...

is this only a visual studio feature? was it defined by c++ standards?

if so which version?

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance or getters. It is standard C++, not specific to Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: Visibility of members doesn't depend on the *instance* of the object but only on the *class* of the object.

`Circle::Circle` can see `radius` because `Circle::Circle` belongs to `Circle` and `radius` belongs to `Circle`.